Comedy about train robbery ruining the sherrif's car
Stupid comedy about two idiots who robbed a train. For robbing, they stole a new car like this one:  This car belonged to the local sheriff. He was crazy about this car! He cleans his car ten times a day!!! Robbers (two idiots) smashed this car while robbing the train. :) I remember that sheriff has two daughters and robbers were in love with these daughters. It was a simple and good movie as I remember. Please help me to find its title.

Can you give us a time period for the movie or when you saw it?

I think that movie from 90x ;) But I saw it in ~2000-2003.

I believe this movie is Free Money from 1998 with Marlon Brando, Charlie Sheen and Thomas Hayden-Church (among many others). Brando's a warden and not a sheriff and the truck is actually black, but the rest is similar. He has 2 twin daughters and his goofy son-in-laws decide to rob a train, wrecking his beloved truck in the proceedings. Check out the trailer here and the summary here (it's a bit too long to quote directly).

Amazing. I was a bit late trying to fit the links in. GMTA. ;) Should I delete my post, then?

Was it Free Money? Sounds just like you're describing with the idiots who love the warden's daughters.

Walrus-like warden, Sven "Swede" Sorenson, a cross between Bluto and
  Wimpy, runs the prison, murders convicts who escape, and has the FBI
  on his trail in the form of agent Karen Polarski, the daughter of the
  town's corrupt judge. Swede's twins tell their father they're pregnant
  (they aren't), so he pushes their dim boyfriends, Bud and Larry, into
  shotgun marriages. He also turns his sons-in-law into slave labor, so
  Bud hatches an escape plan: to rob a train carrying old bills to the
  mint for burning. Larry's his reluctant accomplice. When Bud is
  captured and railroaded into Swede's jail, his death looks certain,
  until he hatches yet another plan that requires Larry's help.

Source: Free Money - imdb
Looked for quite a while and this was the only one I could find that seemed to fit. Released in 1998.

Nevermind, beat to it by sedconds. :O

@Walt that sucks, anyway we can split the bounty (assuming we're correct?)

Kind of you to suggest. I think you deserve it, but whatever Edward decides is fine. Again, assuming this is the flick. ;)

@Walt I asked on meta: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/928/splitting-a-bounty I wonder if we both have 2 votes and the bounty expires if we both get part of the bounty?

Guys thank you! it is what I tried to find! As I understand - I can give the bounty to only one of you:) I'll give bounty to DustinDavis because of factors like: his profile, answer details and because DustinDavis tried to split bounty - it is very generously! But I will accept Walt because his answer right (of course), fully and he offered to cede - very mannerly! Thank you again!!!:))
